# Postman Error with php Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, postman

Hi I have created a php database "login_register"

and from using the php files from [this example](https://github.com/miskoajkula/MYSQL-PHP-Register-Login/tree/master/PHP-FILES) obviously editing where necessary, i then used the POST function in Postman to this url http://localhost:80/login_register/user_control.php

but it has brought up an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Object not found!</title>
        <link rev="made" href="mailto:you@example.com" />
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--/*-->
            <![CDATA[/*>
            <!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Object not found!</h1>
        <p>


    The requested URL was not found on this server.



    If you entered the URL manually please check your
    spelling and try again.



</p>
        <p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the 
            <a href="mailto:you@example.com">webmaster</a>.
        </p>
        <h2>Error 404</h2>
        <address>
            <a href="/">192.168.1.105</a>
            <br />
            <span>Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3</span>
        </address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im basically trying to use android studio and xampp to create a login and register page for an app, any helpregarding whats wrong with the code and also if there are any guides or tutorials for beginners, that would also help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put your PHP files in a place that XAMPP can get to them. The easiest, quickest, thing to do is put the files in XAMPP's htdocs directory (location depends on your OS).

http://sustainablewebdesign.com/book/resources/xampp/ may not match your operating system, but it goes into more detail about how you can configure the Apache instance to use files in directories other than XAMPP's htdocs. So even if the location of the config files don't line up, you could find the right files on your own and use the info there.

Comment: How exactly? Is that php file located at <XAMPP>/htdocs//login_register/user_control.php, or is it in the root like <XAMPP>/htdocs/user_control.php?

Comment: The 3 php files are located in XAMPP/htdocs/ then they are sat in that folder

Comment: So your url should be http://localhost:80/user_control.php instead, since you don't have a login_register folder in htdocs. Or you could make the login_register folder and put the user_control.php there to make the /login_register/user_control.php path exist.

Comment: I have this working now but with an error regarding line 8 of connection.php 
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host     '192.168.98.178' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in
    <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/connection.php</b> on line
    <b>8</b>
    <br />
    Could not connect to db

Comment: Glad to hear you're past the 404 error. Now it sounds like you're having a problem of connecting to the MySQL database (MariaDB). I'll try to help out, but this'll be alot easier if you post a new question with details of what you've tried, what your configuration is, and what the details of the error are. It looks like you have the details of the error in the comment there, but detailing it in the new question would help anyone else that answers too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164206/php-connection-file-error-in-postman thank you!