# Php Connection File Error in Postman

Tags: php, mysql, postman

This is the connection.php file being used to connect to a phpMyAdmin database

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    class DB_Connection {

        private $connect;
        function __construct() {
            $this->connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, db_name)
            or die("Could not connect to db");

        }

        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->connect;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But i seem to get this error when i try to post with Postman

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '192.168.98.178' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in
<b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/connection.php</b> on line
<b>8</b>
<br />
Could not connect to db
```

Comment: `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user`. I'm betting that 192.168.98.178 or (any variations) are not listed. You'll need to add your user at the correct host.

Comment: In my SQL i have SELECT * FROM `users`, how would i go about adding the users to the host?

Comment: You don't need to, you need to add *your* user credentials that you use in your mysqli_connect.

Comment: Where do i do this sorry! sorry if its simple but i've not done this before!!!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I have changed a few things and currently when I use Postman, it doesn't bring up an error but does not bring up any message, this is the user_control.php file https://github.com/miskoajkula/MYSQL-PHP-Register-Login/blob/master/PHP-FILES/user_control.php

Answer (score 0):

Knowing your setup is key here. You're using XAMPP's MySQL server, right? I think you are based on your previous question. What are you passing in for hostname, user, password, and db_name?

XAMPP's Mysql server has a root user and an empty password by default. So having user = 'root' and password = '' should work to get you in. Not good for production, but it'll help you get set up in the meantime.

Past that, learning about MySQL and how to manage it is a good idea. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Comment: This is my config file <?php
define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('username', 'root');
define('password', '');
define('db_name', 'login_register');
?>

Comment: I have changed a few things and currently when I use Postman, it doesn't bring up an error but does not bring up any message, this is the user_control.php file https://github.com/miskoajkula/MYSQL-PHP-Register-Login/blob/master/PHP-FILES/user_control.php

Comment: What does your request in postman look like? What are you expecting to see for that request?

Comment: I expect to see the output for $json['success'] = 'Account created';, my request is for an email and password to be added into the same named headers of my users table within my login_register database

Comment: Have you echo'd from different parts of the code to see what's being run and what isn't? Have you checked your database to see if the users are being created? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/how-to-most-effectively-debug-code has alot of good points on debugging. My strategy has been to isolate parts that I know work from parts that I'm unsure of and keep narrowing it down until I find the problem. Ideally you wouldn't be asking questions about why your site doesn't work unless you know the specific component you're having problems with.